# in eclipse how do I get tomcat run two connected projects when all three require servlet-api.jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, libraries

In eclipse, I have two projects, each populated with servlets.  Project A contains Project B in its build path.

The problem is each of these projects requires servlet-api.jar in order to compile, and matters are made worse when Tomcat ALSO needs servlet-api.jar in its library to run Project A.

When I have servlet-api.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of both Project A and Project B as well as Tomcat, I get a ClassNotFoundException on javax.servlet.Servlet because the multiple instances of servlet-api.jar conflict.  If I delete servlet-api.jar from either of the projects, they can no longer recognize the HTTPWebRequest class, even if I leave servlet-api.jar in Project B and leave Project B in the build path of Project A, the servlets in Project A still won't recognize the HTTPWebRequest class.

If I remove servlet-api.jar from Tomcat, Tomcat can no longer run, and throws a NoClassDefFoundError on javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.  It doesn't seem like there's any way I can get all three to work together since they each need servlet-api.jar to work, and yet if more than one has it there is a conflict.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In 'servers' view configure a tomcat server (if you haven't already done so). In project A and B go to java build path -> Libraries. Click on add library -> server runtime and then select tomcat runtime (which you configured via 'servers' view). Following links give you further information.

adding tomcat as a server in eclipse.
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, though this did not fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the errors were caused by the init methods in two of the classes in Project B. After spending multiple days trying everything possible, the solution in the end was to merge the two projects.

Things that did not work include:

- deleting servlet-api.jar from either of the projects, both of the projects, or from Tomcat
- adding or removing project B from project A's build path (though this was necessary to compile A)
- adding project B under Tomcat's build path (though it did seem to help)
- removing startup calls from web.xml to keep the init() method from being called (this allowed Tomcat to start without any errors, but then the project didn't work

We may have tried a few other things, but in the end, removing project B and merging the files with A was what allowed it to work.